# Flutter gridview menu on tap function is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create an application in flutter latest version. I would like to create fragments instead of pages. Now in homepage fragment, I tried to make a gridview menu which has 6 menu item. I am stuck at onTap function because I wanted to move another fragment when the menu is tapped. its not working. I am sharing my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:folder/fragments/fragment_form.dart';

class HomeFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            //stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
            colors: [
              Colors.teal[50],
              Colors.cyan[50],
              Colors.blue[50],
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: new Center(
          child: new HomepageFragment(),
        )
    );
  }

}

class HomepageFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[
          MyMenu(titleText: "Add Complain", iconImage: Icons.add_box, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 0),
          MyMenu(titleText: "Log In", iconImage: Icons.account_box, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 1),
          MyMenu(titleText: "About App", iconImage: Icons.airplay, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 2),
          MyMenu(titleText: "How we Work", iconImage: Icons.alarm_on, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 3),
          MyMenu(titleText: "All Complains ", iconImage: Icons.apps, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 4),
          MyMenu(titleText: "Privacy", iconImage: Icons.assistant, iconColor: Colors.cyan, position: 5),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyMenu extends StatelessWidget {

  MyMenu({this.titleText, this.iconImage, this.iconColor, this.position});
  final String titleText;
  final IconData iconImage;
  final MaterialColor iconColor;
  final int position;


  _getMenuTem(position){
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return new FormFragment();
      case 1:
        return new FormFragment();
      case 2:
        return new FormFragment();
      case 3:
        return new FormFragment();

      default:
        return new Text("Something went wrong");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => _getMenuTem(position),
        onLongPress: () => _getMenuTem(position),
        splashColor: Colors.green,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                iconImage,
                size: 100.0,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
              Text(titleText, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.teal[800])),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you want?

Comment: I want that, when i tap to a card, its should take me to another fragment like form fragment as i included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_getMenuTem` method is returning a `Widget` so you can't get the beaviour you expected.

TO `navigate` to a new screen, you need to use the `Navigator` class:

> **Example** :
> `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));`

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
_getMenuTem(position, context) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        // navigate to specific screen
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FormFragment(),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 1:
        // navigate to specific screen
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FormFragment(),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        // navigate to specific screen
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FormFragment(),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 3:
        // navigate to specific screen
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FormFragment(),
          ),
        );
        break;
      default:
        return new Text("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I replaced my _getMenuTem() function with your one. now an error is showing, 
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No Material widget found.

Comment: Try wrapping your `MyMenu` widget `Card` in a `Scaffold` @MdSabbirAhmed

Comment: Yes i tried. i coded scafold and appbar in another page, so its showing an error, bottom overflowing and appbar is hiding.

Comment: Can you update your question with the Widget you are talking about ?

Comment: I wrapped mymenu widget card in a scafold, so now appbar is hiding and bottom overflowing, but on tap fragment is changing. basically i keep scafold, appbar in another page called home page, so the fragment is opening but appbar is hiding.

Comment: I guess that should be another question since your your main issue was basically solved here. @MdSabbirAhmed

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Can you help me to solve this problem too. actually i am new in flutter.

Comment: Can you create a Github gist showing the proper widget hierarchy, it'll be easy to tell what's wrong that way.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole code. What i want is, in my fragment_home.dart, i have placed some card like menu, on tap of those menu, i need to change just the fragments.

https://github.com/sabbir073/First-Flutter-App

I am waiting for you reply. Thanks in advance for this big help. You made my day <3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220180/discussion-between-md-sabbir-ahmed-and-void).